# Leiningen install Error - not bit 64 compatible

Tags: clojure, windows-10, leiningen

I am having Leiningen install issues. I've installed the JAVA JDK and Clojure also setup the System Variable Paths but when I try to install Leiningen it's a no go.

I am installing it on a Windows 10 machine. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: leiningen will always supply its own clojure, installing clojure is not a prerequisite for leiningen

Comment: The actual error I am getting in a pop-up is: lein.exe cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows. I tried (lien help) and I get the error.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? can you outline your exact steps?

Comment: I typed in ( lein help task ) and the exact error reads: This version of ....path\to\lein\bin\lein.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you are running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.